Necessity Of Reiterated Line In Proof Of Material Implication
As far as I can tell, the following proof of material implication is valid. However, I am concerned by the apparent necessity of reiterating line 9 at line 11. Does that render the proof invalid, or does it (as I suspect) simply indicate that a more efficient proof exists? Left margin numbers indicate dependency.
Prove: $\lnot\ P\vee\ Q\vdash\ P\rightarrow\ Q$.
1     $(1)\ \ \lnot\ P\vee\ Q$    Premise                                                         $\therefore\ P\rightarrow\ Q$
2     $(2)\ \ \lnot\ P$     Assumption A
3     $(3)\ \ P$        Assumption B
4     $(4)\ \ \lnot\ Q$    Assumption C
2,3   $(5)\ \ \lnot\ P\land\ P$            $2,3;\ \land\ I$
2,3   $(6)\ \ \lnot\lnot\ Q$                $4,5;\ \lnot\ I$          [C discharged]
2,3   $(7)\ \ Q$                          $6;\ \lnot\ E$
2     $(8)\ \ P\rightarrow\ Q$              $3,7;\ \rightarrow\ I$            [B discharged]
9     $(9)\ \ Q$       Assumption D
10    $(10)\ \ P$     Assumption E
9     $(11)\ \ Q$     Reiteration of 9
9    $(12)\ \ P\rightarrow\ Q$           $10,11;\ \rightarrow\ I$        [E discharged]
1     $(13)\ \ P\rightarrow\ Q$            $1,2,8,9,11;\ \vee\ E$  [A & D discharged]                  QED

The other thread concerns supplying a proof, and one of a distinct logical equivalence. I have a proof, or believe that I have, and want to know whether a reiterated line in it indicates a lack of efficiency, or whether it is unavoidable.

Many thanks @Mauro Allegranza. I have worked out how to avoid the reiteration; once Q is assumed (in line 9), P>Q follows immediately (if the consequent of a conditional obtains, then the conditional obtains, irrespective of whether the consequent follows from the antecedent). Thus lines 10 and 11 are not required.
